# Array dinâmico em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Estou tentando gerar um *array* formado por outros *arrays* dinamicamente. Por exemplo:

```
check = function (title, filter) {
        if (checked.indexOf(title) !== -1) {
            checked[title].push(filter);
        } else {
            checked.push(title);
        }
};

check('arraypai','conteudo');
check('arraypai','outroconteudo');
```

De forma que o resultado seria:

```
[
 arraypai[conteudo,outroconteudo]
]
```

e depois...

```
check('arraymae','coisa');
check('arraymae','outracoisa');
```

e o resultado seria:

```
[
 arraypai[conteudo, outroconteudo],
 arraymae[coisa, outracoisa]
]
```

Comment: Acho que o que você quer é um dicionário de arrays, não? Tipo: `{ arraypai:[conteudo, outroconteudo], arraymae:[coisa, outracoisa] }`. Alternativamente, você pode ter um array de pares nome/array, tipo: `[{nome:arraypai, array:[conteudo, outroconteudo]}, {nome:arraymae, array:[coisa, outracoisa]}]`. P.S. se for o primeiro caso, basta substituir `checked.push(title)` por `checked[title] = [filter]`.

Comment: Precisa ser array dentro de array, porque depois, em outro momento, preciso dar um .join(',') em cada array principal.

Comment: Então você está com problemas, pois o máximo que você vai conseguir é `[[conteudo, outroconteudo], [coisa, outracoisa]]`. Não existem arrays associativos no JavaScript...

Comment: Se eu conseguir criar os arrays dentro de um objeto, dicionário de arrays, como mencionou, ainda funcionaria.

Comment: O mais próximo de um array associativo verdadeiro em JS é um objeto literal, como sugerido pelo @mgibsonbr. Qualquer coisa, reformula a pergunta :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a questão é "associar o nome X com o array Y", então a melhor forma de se fazer é usando um dicionário de arrays (i.e. um objeto simples, cujas chaves são nomes e cujos valores são arrays):

```js
var checked = {};

check = function (title, filter) {
        if (checked[title] !== undefined) { // Testa se a chave existe
            checked[title].push(filter);    // Adiciona um elemento no array
        } else {
            checked[title] = [filter];      // Se não existe, cria um array com um elemento
        }
};

check('arraypai','conteudo');
check('arraypai','outroconteudo');
check('arraymae','coisa');
check('arraymae','outracoisa');

document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(checked) + "<br/>" +
  checked["arraypai"].join(", ") + "<br/>" +
  checked.arraymae.join(", ");
```

```html
<span id="saida"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente tudo o que você quiser fazer com array associativo pode ser feito com objetos.

Para imprimir, por exemplo, você pode iterar sobre as chaves (atributos) do objeto, como no exemplo a seguir:

```js
var checked = {};

var check = function (title, filter) {
    if (checked[title]) checked[title].push(filter);
    else checked[title] = [ filter ];
};

var compilar = function(){
    var str = "";
    for(var key in checked){
        str += key + "[" + checked[key].toString() + "];";
    }
    print(str + "<br />");
};

check('arraypai','conteudo');
check('arraypai','outroconteudo');
compilar();




// Função de comodidade para imprimir o resultado. Ignore-a :)
function print(source){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = source;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```